# Javascript regex, replacing numbers with manipulated number

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
"4/7/12"
```

and I would like to replace each number with this formula:
    (25 - x) where 'x' is the number from the string.

For example:
    "4/7/12" would be translated into: "21/18/13"

How can I do this using 'replace()' and Regex ??

```
var player_move = "5/7/9";
var translated_pm = player_move.replace(/\/\*?/, 25 - /$1/);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var translated_pm = player_move.replace(/\d+/g, function (x){return 25 - parseInt(x)});
```

Comment: This solution is even better because it allows me to use the following string:
str = 1/*3/9/*20

Answer (score 2):

Try this, all in one line:

```js
var player_move = "5/7/9";

var new_move = player_move.split('/').map(function(number) { return 25 - Number(number); }).join('/');

alert(new_move);
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use a regex?

[JsBin example](https://jsbin.com/vapixi/1/edit?js,console)

**without regex**

This might be a better way to do it:

```
var n = "4/7/12".split('/').map(function(el) {
  return 25 - Number(el); // Number not needed here bc of coercion but I like it here
}).join('/');
```

**regexp**

With `.replace`, you can pass in a function like so:

```
var re = "4/7/12".replace(/\d+/g, function(match) {
  return 25 - match;
})
```

Comment: You are welcome! I actually will edit with a pretty simple solution with a slight edit to your original code...